# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in breadcrumbs function

Tags: drupal, foreach, invalid-argument

I have an invalid argument suplied for foreach() on the following code and I can't figure out why..

```
function empuls_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
  if (!empty($breadcrumb))
      {
         foreach($breadcrumb as $k => $v) {
             foreach ($v as $key=>$value){
           $breadcrumb[$k][$key]='<span>'.$value.'</span>';
        }
        }
   return '<div class="breadcrumb">'. implode(' ', $breadcrumb['breadcrumb']) .'</div>';
  }
 }
```

This is a code used on a Drupal theme, the breadcrumb is showing without a problem still I would like the warning to be solved of course.
Thanks for taking a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume `$breadcrumb` isn't iterable. Instead of `!empty` check if it's `is_array()` (assuming you expect an array and nor some other iterable PHP object)

You should update your question with a specific error. It could be the inner `for` that's causing the problem if the `$breadcrumb` array doesn't contain arrays since you do no type checking inside.

If it is available to you I would recommend trying a `dpm($breadcrumb)` to see the structure of the variable this function is receiving.

Comment: If I change !empty with !is_array it dissapears completely (the error and the breadcrumbs). If I hange !is_array to is_array is shows again but with the warning message (same as mentioned above).
Thanks for taking a look into it.

Comment: Yes, I let a typo in - sorry! Check the structure of the data tha is being passed into the array, it will probably be not as you expect

Answer (score 0):

You have to test variable before use it :

```
function empuls_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
  if (!empty($breadcrumb) && (is_array($breadcrumb) || is_object($breadcrumb))){
         foreach($breadcrumb as $k => $v) {
             if(is_array($v) || is_object($v)){
               foreach ($v as $key=>$value){
                    $breadcrumb[$k][$key]='<span>'.$value.'</span>';
               }
            }
        }
   return '<div class="breadcrumb">'. implode(' ', $breadcrumb['breadcrumb']) .'</div>';
  }
 }
```